# Kotlin Date.daysAfter function different return value with the same arguments

Tags: android, date, kotlin

I've been wondering why my code is buggy, I discovered possible bug.

```
    fun daysAfter(date: Date): Int {
    Log.d("DayLayout", "date arg - $date")
    Log.d("DayLayout", "firstDate.time - " + firstDate.time.toString())
    val ret = date.daysAfter(firstDate.time).toInt()
    Log.d("DayLayout", "day after - " + ret)
    return ret
}
```

First invocation of given function

> D/DayLayout: date arg - Sun Jan 08 09:48:57 EST 2017
>
> D/DayLayout: firstDate.time - Sun Jan 01 09:49:04 EST 2017
>
> D/DayLayout: day after - 6

Second invocation, few secs later

> D/DayLayout: date arg - Sun Jan 08 09:49:04 EST 2017
>
> D/DayLayout: firstDate.time - Sun Jan 01 09:49:04 EST 2017
>
> D/DayLayout: day after - 7

How is that even possible? I'm missing something, function with the same arguments should return the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm missing something, function with the same arguments should return the same value.

But you aren't calling it with the same values. You are calling it with two different values.

First, you are comparing these two dates:

```
date arg - Sun Jan 08 09:48:57 EST 2017
                         ^^^^^
firstDate.time - Sun Jan 01 09:49:04 EST 2017
```

And then you compare:

```
date arg - Sun Jan 08 09:49:04 EST 2017
                         ^^^^^
firstDate.time - Sun Jan 01 09:49:04 EST 2017
```

Just looking at the times, it seems obvious why the first invocation gives a different answer from the second - because there IS a different number of days between them. Look at the times. In the first one, you are 6 days, 23 hours, and 53 seconds from the `firstDate`. In the second you are *exactly* 7 days.